# Unable to sign-in because of Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Application error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity-3

Just trying to get simple authentication working, but receive exception when trying to login:

Seeded the DB with:

```
user = new ApplicationUser
{
    FirstName = "John",
    LastName = "Smith",
    UserName = "jsmith",
    Email = "jsmith@gmail.com",
    EmailConfirmed = true,
    LockoutEnabled = false
};
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "P@ssW4rd");
```

Logging in...

```
var b = await _securityManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Username);
try
{
    var result = await _loginManager.PasswordSignInAsync(b.UserName, 
                        model.Password, false, lockoutOnFailure: false);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        return RedirectToReturnUrl(returnUrl);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
}
```

The following exception is caught:

> No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme:
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Application

So then my configuration...

Startup.cs `ConfigureServices`

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Startup.cs `Configure`

```
app.UseIdentity();
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I missed the fact that `app.UseIdentity();` must go before `app.UseMvc();`